# "Dummy" question closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, specific-question

This question recently caught my attention:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/29735936/3225495

From the title and first sentence, it seems like a (poorly-worded) but real question.  The second sentence is what gets me:

> May be this question does not meet stackoverflow's quality standards, but I need to add some question to test site's interface. It's my lab in University.

If I'm understanding correctly, the poster is not really interested in an answer - they just "needed to add some question" for an assignment.

Since this "question" was closed as a duplicate, it will not be automatically deleted by the system.  Should the asker's intent be taken into account here, and would that justify deleting this post?

EDIT:
Clarification - I absolutely think it should be deleted.  My concern was that being closed as a duplicate would *prevent* it from being culled.

Comment: It doesn't need to be auto culled by the system - it's gone. It's goner than a goneburger.

Comment: This same user has gone on to make several other similar posts, now answers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29741104

Comment: And the winner of the Spring 2015 Polishing A Turd Award is: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29735936/revisions

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett screenshot for us low-rep peons?

Comment: @Pureferret http://i.imgur.com/se4eFFe.png The user managed to slip this gem of an edit in between the closed-as-duplicate and delete notices...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I'm going to be blunt.

I don't care what reason they had to ask the question, but if it's poor quality, it will be treated like any other poor quality question on Stack Overflow.  If this means it gets deleted as a result, so be it.

They may have whatever reason to post it, but their reasoning doesn't exempt them from the standards we've got on the site.

Comment: I'd even go further and add a comment stating that we're unhappy with a teacher/prof giving such an assignment as it can obviously lead to low quality posts. We're perfectly happy with a reference to SO (as a platform to ask questions in case there are any), but not with assigning people to ask questions here.

Comment: Yes, stackoverflow is known for its quality. Giving task just to add question is immoral. If some teacher wants to give assignment, he should check what question is getting post.

Comment: @Panther it is not a question of morality, rather it is a question of ethical standards. Calling on the professor's moral state is a bit extreme and is not correct in this context. The professor's ethics are what are at risk if they assign their students the task of adding questions to SO for no actual reason.

Comment: @JohnnyCoder sorry wrong choice of word. I meant ethics onlys. Seems i need to be active on english learner in stack exchagne also :-)

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit It's possible that the assignment wasn't specifically to post a question, but to do research on interfaces. The poster could then have taken it upon themselves "to test site's interface" with the garbage question. Hopefully this is just one inconsiderate student and not an entire class.

Comment: @BiscuitBaker sure it's possible but if it's the case the student probably won't tell the teacher/prof so no harm done. Even if he would tell the teacher all negativity would probably focus on the student. If it's not the case then the teacher can and should take appropriate measures...

Comment: The more interesting case is that if someone posts a good question for bad reason, it should be kept, which seems obviously correct.